# psycopg2: break up of time taken

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to fetch data from remote postgresql server

```
    con = psycopg2.connect(host=server_host, database=server_dbname, user=server_username, password=server_password,cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
    cursor = con.cursor()
    query = f"""
    SELECT "devicedata"."id",
           "devicedata"."sn",
           "devicedata"."time",
           "devicedata"."icsz1",
    FROM "devicedata"
    WHERE "devicedata"."sn" = %s
    ORDER BY "devicedata"."id" DESC
    LIMIT 100000
    """
    params = ("TestDevice", )
    device_data = cursor.fetchall()
```

this query has almost `100k` rows to get

i have done the indexing and the try to know the time taken to execute the query by

```
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE
    SELECT "devicedata"."id",
           "devicedata"."sn",
           "devicedata"."time",
           "devicedata"."icsz1",
    FROM "devicedata"
    WHERE "devicedata"."sn" = 'TestDevice'
    ORDER BY "devicedata"."id" DESC
    LIMIT 100000
```

the time taken it shows is

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=0.00..7514.40 rows=100000 width=29) (actual time=0.017..34.402 rows=100000 loops=1)
  Output: id, sn, "time", icsz1
  ->  Seq Scan on public.devicedata  (cost=0.00..222938.09 rows=2966813 width=29) (actual time=0.016..28.667 rows=100000 loops=1)
        Output: id, sn, "time", icsz1
        Filter: (devicedata.sn = 'TestDevice'::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 154658
Planning time: 0.154 ms
Execution time: 37.451 ms
```

But if it try to get the time

like

```
import time
start = time.time()

.... psycopg2 code here to fetch

print(f'Time: {time.time() - start}')
```

it says 2.5 sec

So how to get the break up of the time

1. server-side query execution time
2. client latency
3. data transfertime
4. python processing time

Comment: Your plan does not match your query.  Satisfying the ORDER BY would require either a sort or an index scan.

Comment: i dont know about that, but explain shows whatever it is